# Quantifying covariate shift

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization, covariate-shift

I'm reading the paper "[Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)" by Ioffe and Szegedy, which discusses Batch Normalization as a way to reduce the internal covariate shift in the activations of the NN layers. Although the paper includes a graphical representation comparing the distribution of a single node in a layer with and without Batch Normalization (BN), it lacks a quantitative metric for assessing the extent of covariate shift. I'm wondering if there is a metric for quantifying the covariate shift.